# User state in Parsec

Tags: haskell, state, parsec

I'm parsing an expression using Parsec and I want to keep track of variables in these expressions using the user state in Parsec. Unfortunately I don't really get how to do it.

Given the following code:

```
import Data.Set as Set
inp = "$x = $y + $z"

data Var = V String

var = do char '$'
      n <- many1 letter
      let v = Var n
       -- I want to modify the set of variables here
      return v

parseAssignment = ... -- parses the above assignment

run = case runIdentity $ runParserT parseAssignment Set.empty "" inp of
                   Left err -> ...
                   Right -> ...
```

So, the `u` in `ParsecT s u m a` would be `Set.Set`. But how would I integrate the state update into `var`?

I tried something like `modify $ Set.insert v`, but this doesn't work, since `Set.Set` is not a state monad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, Yuras' suggestion of `updateParserState` is not optimal (you'd use that function if you're looking to modify Parsec's internal state *as well*); instead you should pass a function that works over your custom user state (i.e. of type `u -> u`) to `modifyState`, such as in this example:

```
expr  = do
  x <- identifier
  modifyState (+1)
  -- ^ in this example, our type u is Int
  return (Id x)
```

or use any combination of the `getState` and `putState` functions. For your case, you'd do something like:

```
modifyState (Set.insert v)
```

See [this link](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3aputState) for more info.

For a more tutorial-like introduction to working with user state in Parsec, [this document](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf), though old, should be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need - could have looked at that function earlier... I somehow thought modifyState was related to modify from Control.Monad.State.

Comment: @bzn: It is related, though! If you think of Parsec as a state monad holding just the user state, they do the same thing. They differ only because `modifyState` ignores Parsec's internal state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [updateParserState](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3aupdateParserState)

Comment: thanks, that works, but as Raeez Lorgat said, modifyState seems to be the function I need.

Comment: please consider adding some example/explanation to your answer